# ERROR in FCK EDITOR

Tags: fckeditor

i am using FCK EDITOR latest version 2.6.4.1 and i found an ERROR while uploading an IMAGE.

The Error is as follows.

File Not Found
Firefox can't find the file at http://174.120.17.194/~newlife/includes/FCKeditor_Latest/editor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=http://174.120.17.194/~newlife/includes/FCKeditor_Latest/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php.

```
* Could the item have been renamed, removed, or relocated?
* Is there a spelling, capitalization, or other typographical error in the address?
* Do you have sufficient access permissions to the requested item?
```

This is the ERROR thrown by the browser. I changed all the setting that related to server. But still i cant able to solve the problem.

But the same is working in my local machine. But while i upload it in server it is not responding. can anybody help me at this critical issue.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I'm assuming you are using PHP according to the URL posted. The no. 1 problem with uploading files to a server is usually write permissions. Are you sure you checked that?